# What is an expression for something that appears important/valuable but actually isn't that important/valuable

Tags: phrases

For example, I believe that pie charts of your spending are presented as being important and valuable, but they rarely result in actual better spending habits. Therefore, pie charts of your spending are ________.

While a single word is appreciated, I would prefer an expression like "pie charts of your spending are **a red herring**" (but "red herring" isn't *quite* right).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the title of the question (a generalism) doesn’t correspond to the particular concern expressed in the question.

Comment: @David I'm not sure what you meant exactly, but I changed the title to ask for an expression rather than a term. Is that what you were getting at? I'm new at this, so I appreciate the help.

Comment: I thought I had already made a comment that had for some reason been removed. To repeat, your concern is not that pie charts are unimportant in a general sense, but in the specific sense that “they do not lead to better spending habits”. My point is that no phrase by itself can convey that idea, which needs to be included in your sample sentence: “pie charts of your spending are ......... in relation to producing better spending habits.” In which case I am sure you can supply suitable words (irrelevant, ineffective, useless) yourself.

Comment: Cut the kid some slack it's a fair question generating interesting and varied answers mate

Comment: @David Actually, what I'm looking for is an expression to communicate something that is generally considered useful actually isn't. Perhaps my example could be better as you point out, but it's still a legitimate question IMHO.

Comment: @ConfusedSoul — In an effort to help diminish your confusion, I would point out that your comment is, by default, addressed to the poster. If it was intended for my humble self, you should have started with an at symbol (only one allowed per comment). That way the intended recipient is alerted. (The poster is always alerted, regardless.) As for your comment, I would not normally respond, but as I am here, all I would say is that is how I see it, and as you have provided no argument for your viewpoint, there is nothing to respond to.

Answer (score 4):

To be exact, an object that attains more attention and importance than it deserves can be called "overrated" in a single word.

"Overestimated importance" is an expression that can fulfill the same linguistic function.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that such pie-charts are of ***spurious*** value.

OED meaning of *spurious* - sense 3 is the important one:

*Superficially resembling or simulating, but lacking the genuine character or qualities of, something; not true or genuine; false, sham, counterfeit:*

Answer (score 1):

The term that comes to mind is **[fool's gold](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fool's+gold)**. "Something that seems more promising than it really is."

Answer (score 1):

How about boondoggle?

noun
1.
work or activity that is wasteful or pointless but gives the appearance of having value.
"writing off the cold fusion phenomenon as a boondoggle best buried in literature"

Answer (score 0):

How about [dud](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dud)?

> *informal* - One that is disappointingly ineffective or unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

**superfluous**

> not necessary or relevant; uncalled-for (Collins at the [free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/superfluous))

Your example:

> I believe that pie charts of your spending are presented as being important and valuable, but they rarely result in actual better spending habits. Therefore, pie charts of your spending are **superfluous**.

This means that they are unnecessary.